# Objects property not set

Tags: objective-c, arrays, macos

I have this short method that is parsing a string.

```
NSMutableArray *aircraftMutableArray;
- (void)parseAircraftRotations:(NSString*)inText
    {
    aircraftMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *inTextArray = [inText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    for (NSString*line in inTextArray)
    {
        if ([line length] > 0)
        {
            if ([[line substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"-"])
            {
                aircraft = [[AirCraft alloc] init];
                [aircraft setRegistration:[line substringFromIndex:1]];
                [aircraftMutableArray addObject:aircraft];
                aircraft = nil;
            }
        }
    }

    for (AirCraft *ac in aircraftMutableArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [ac registration]);
    }
}
```

My problem now is that the NSLog prints out the correct number of lines, but the [ac registration] is null on each line. Pls help.

Comment: What does your [AirCraft registration] method look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the property of the Aircraft object was defined like this

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *registration;
```

Should be strong

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *registration;
```